# How to round PHP numeral value with 3 decimal?

Tags: php, function, rounding, precision

`$val = 95454545.455`

How to round `$val` so the result will be `95454546`?

Because using `round()` only return `95454545`

**EDIT**

`ceil()` is almost correct, but if `$val = 95454545.444`, I want the function return to `95454545`

Regards,
Elmer

Comment: Using what mathematical logic should `.455` round the whole number 1 up and `.444` round down?

Comment: the rounding rules are, if the floating point precision number is 5 or more, then round up, else, round down. but if there is more than one floating point precision number like `$var = 1.445`, the `round()` function should round it up to `2` because number `5` will round up `4` -> `5`, then, the second `5` will round up the last `4` -> `5`, then, the third `5` will round up number `1` -> `2`

Comment: yes @HankyPanky, it should be like that.

Comment: But why should it be like that? Is that a new theory in mathematics? That requirement makes no sense, writing some custom if else will do the job for you.

Comment: that would be mathematically wrong I believe? @JohnElmerSemaya

Comment: @HankyPanky the client wants it like that

Comment: Please tell them to take a course in Kindergarten Mathematics :)

Comment: Well, thx for the response, I think I'll explain to my client that it is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I've found the formula for this kind of problem.
ex:

`$var = 95454545.454`

I only have to add `0.055` value in it.

`$new_var = $var + 0.055` -> `$new_var = 95454545.509`

`$result = round($new_var)` -> `$result = 95454546`

Answer (score 0):

Use ceil() instead which will round to the next big value,

```
echo ceil($val);
```

**UPDATE**

You can acheive more precision with round() and HALF UP flag,

```
echo round(95454545.544, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); //95454546

echo round(95454545.44, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); //95454545
```

Comment: please check the updated question, the first one lacks more explanation

Comment: @JohnElmerSemaya see the updated answer hope that will be of  help.

Comment: No Need for `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` that's the default mode already. Problem is with OP's requirement, not your answer.

Comment: @Vincent, have you tried `echo round(95454545.454, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);`, because when I tried, only return `95454545`

Comment: yes because it is supposed to be like that right? its not half up

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
ceil — Round fractions up, Returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value if necessary.

```
<?php
$val = 95454545.455;
$result = ceil($val);
echo 'Result '.$result;
?>
```

Comment: please check the updated question, the first one lacks more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this number_format it will round up decimal numbers

```
<?php
$val = 95454545.455;
$result = number_format($val , 3, '.', ',');
echo 'Result '.$result;
<?
```

Comment: this is the result `Result 95,454,545.455`